# How can i scroll to the bottom of the fragment on a nestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, scroll

I have a `fragment` with a **nestedScrollView** with some static information and some `LinearLayouts` with visibility **GONE**.

Those `LinearLayout` get fills after this `fragment` get opened and then I set the visibility of those Layouts on **VISIBLE**. I want just to scroll to the bottom of this fragment when this info load.

I tried with the property ***descendantFocusability*** and using the **`fullscroll function`** on this **nestedScrollView**, but I get no results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While load the fragment try to call this in `onCreateview()` in your fragment for scroll at the bottom.

```
Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    };
    scrollView.post(runnable);
```

Happy coding!!